# AWS CloudFormation stack: add load balancer listener based on condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I'm trying to use CloudFormation to build up a list of Load balancer listeners and have an optional parameter `TCPPort1` set as a listener **only** if that value has been set.

I've used `Condition` in other places but if I use it at the listener level I get the error:
`The following resource(s) failed to create: [LoadBalancer]. . Rollback requested by user.`
`Encountered unsupported property Condition`

```
LoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      HealthCheck:
        HealthyThreshold: '2'
        Interval: '15'
        Target: 'HTTP:9000/'
        Timeout: '5'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '10'
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: TCPPort1
          Condition: HasTCPPort1
          InstanceProtocol: HTTP
          LoadBalancerPort: TCPPort1
          SSLCertificateId: !If
            - HasLoadBalancerCertificateARN
            - !Ref LoadBalancerCertificateARN
            - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
          Protocol: !If
            - HasLoadBalancerCertificateARN
            - HTTPS
            - HTTP
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
        - 'Fn::ImportValue':
              !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetAPublic'
        - 'Fn::ImportValue':
              !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetBPublic'
        - 'Fn::ImportValue':
              !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetCPublic'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      Instances:
        - !Ref Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Using classic load balancer...

```
LoadBalancer:
  Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
  Properties:
    HealthCheck:
      HealthyThreshold: '2'
      Interval: '15'
      Target: 'HTTP:9000/'
      Timeout: '5'
      UnhealthyThreshold: '10'
    Listeners: !If 'HasTCPPort1'
      -
        - InstancePort: TCPPort1
          Condition: HasTCPPort1
          InstanceProtocol: HTTP
          LoadBalancerPort: TCPPort1
          SSLCertificateId: !If
            - HasLoadBalancerCertificateARN
            - !Ref LoadBalancerCertificateARN
            - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
          Protocol: !If
            - HasLoadBalancerCertificateARN
            - HTTPS
            - HTTP
      - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue' 
    Scheme: internet-facing
    Subnets:
      - 'Fn::ImportValue':
            !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetAPublic'
      - 'Fn::ImportValue':
            !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetBPublic'
      - 'Fn::ImportValue':
            !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetCPublic'
    SecurityGroups:
      - !Ref SecurityGroup
    Instances:
      - !Ref Server
```

Comment: Updated answer to use a classic load balancer... Its not really considered good practice to use these anymore so might be worth using an application/network load balancer.

Comment: wish I could, I'm only editing a script that's not really in my control.  There are quite a few like this and wouldn't want to mess up the consistency